# Can't reach Jupyter Notebooks on Azure Deep Learning Virtual Machine

Tags: python, azure, jupyter-notebook, jupyterhub, azure-dsvm

I followed the instructions [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/data-science-virtual-machine/linux-dsvm-intro#jupyter-notebook).

I am on the Ubuntu VM via SSH. 
I tried to access IP:8000 but Chrome says the Site can't be reached. Port 8000 is indeed open by default as mentioned in the docs.

Instructions don't mention if I have to start `jupyterhub` so I tried that and got this error -

```
username@fastai:~ $ jupyterhub
[I 2018-04-02 00:25:41.018 JupyterHub app:871] Writing cookie_secret to /home/username/jupyterhub_cookie_secret
[I 2018-04-02 00:25:41.036 alembic.runtime.migration migration:117] Context impl SQLiteImpl.
[I 2018-04-02 00:25:41.037 alembic.runtime.migration migration:122] Will assume non-transactional DDL.
[I 2018-04-02 00:25:41.067 alembic.runtime.migration migration:327] Running stamp_revision  -> 3ec6993fe20c
[W 2018-04-02 00:25:41.388 JupyterHub app:955] No admin users, admin interface will be unavailable.
[W 2018-04-02 00:25:41.389 JupyterHub app:956] Add any administrative users to `c.Authenticator.admin_users` in config.
[I 2018-04-02 00:25:41.389 JupyterHub app:983] Not using whitelist. Any authenticated user will be allowed.
[E 2018-04-02 00:25:41.414 JupyterHub app:1525] Failed to bind hub to http://127.0.0.1:8081/hub/
[E 2018-04-02 00:25:41.414 JupyterHub app:1623]
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/anaconda/envs/py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/jupyterhub/app.py", line 1621, in launch_instance_async
        yield self.start()
      File "/anaconda/envs/py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/jupyterhub/app.py", line 1523, in start
        self.http_server.listen(self.hub_port, address=self.hub_ip)
      File "/anaconda/envs/py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tornado/tcpserver.py", line 142, in listen
        sockets = bind_sockets(port, address=address)
      File "/anaconda/envs/py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tornado/netutil.py", line 197, in bind_sockets
        sock.bind(sockaddr)
    OSError: [Errno 98] Address already in use
```

Before I read about jupyterhub in the docs, I tried starting `jupyter notebook` which gave me this error.

```
[C 04:00:12.963 NotebookApp] Bad config encountered during initialization:
[C 04:00:12.963 NotebookApp] No such notebook dir: ''/dsvm/Notebooks''
```

It seemed to run fine after generating a config file using `jupyter notebook --generate-config` and editing it but I still couldn't reach it via Chrome despite opening up all ports.

**UPDATE**
Today I installed an X2Go client and found the [jupyter notebook icon](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/data-science-virtual-machine/dsvm-ubuntu-intro#jupyter-notebook) on the desktop but starting that threw this error -
    Failed to run Jupyter.desktop
    Failed to parse the desktop file: Key file contains line '/anaconda/pkgs/notebook-5.4.0-py27_0/info/icon.png' which is not a key-value pair, group, or comment

Looks like that file calls jupyter notebook which throws the same error as before.

Comment: did you use **Jupyter Lab** app instead?  It is launching and you should use **https://<ip address | localhost>:9999**.  And for me, I entered https://localhost:8000, Jupyter notebook also working fine.

Comment: 8000 isn't reachable for me so I am guessing 9999 won't work either.. most blog posts I saw didn't mention the problem I am facing so I am guessing they changed the image a little bit which is causing my issue

Comment: @pradhyo I went under "Applications" and opened JupyterHub via the dropdown option in "Development." I also opened the port 9999 for all inbound traffic. This seemed to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was caused by a bug which has since been fixed on the later versions of the Deep learning VM.

See [this Github issue](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/6811) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

JupyterHub should be running on port 8000 at startup. Can you double-check its status with *systemctl status jupyterhub*? And have you double-checked in the portal that port 8000 is open?

If JupyterHub reports that it's running and listening on port 8000, there may be a firewall blocking the connection. Some users have had success with forwarding port 8000 over SSH in this case, then connecting to localhost:8000.

Comment: Thanks Paul, I had deleted the VM and have no way of checking it now.